# Error when executing a test whose .sql file has variable (Robot Framework)

Tags: python, variables, automation, robotframework

I have the following situation, could you help me?

I would like to leave some dynamic data (variables) inside my .sql file and execute my test correctly in .robot file.

However, when I go to do my test, it returns an error, that is, the variable is not mounted correctly. I think I'm leaving something "behind".

Could anyone help me?

> **.sql file below (I want my variable name):**

```
INSERT INTO TBMENSAGEMITEM (NUM_MESSAGE, SEQUENCE)
VALUES (@NUMERO_MENSAGEM, ${NAMES})
```

> **.robot file below:**

```
*** Variables ***
${NAMES}                          'JOAO'

*** Test Cases ***
Test Variable

${file}   Get File             ${EXECDIR}/spb/scripts/SQL/fileTest.sql
${NAMES}   Replace Variables    ${file}

  Execute Sql Script    ${NAMES}
```

> **Error below:**

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:
```

I'm sure I'm wrong in my .robot file. But I don't know where.

Could anyone help?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the actual error.

Comment: That error seems to be missing a lot of detail. Also, have you examined the value of `${name}` immediately before doing the query to see if it is what you think it is?

Comment: Bryan, yes. The variable is printing what I need.

Even, for testing purposes, I created a simple variable and sent it. Same mistake.

If I run the test with .sql file without variable, it is done successfully!
That is, the problem is in the variable or some other config...

Comment: If you get the same problem with a hard-coded string, then the problem isn't with how you're reading the file or replacing the variables, it's how you're running the file. You haven't showed that in the question so it's going to be hard for us to guess what you're doing.

Comment: I edited and added how I call the file. But there is no secret...

I added and follows here too: Run Sql Script ${NAMES}

Hope you can help me!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Bryan, i edited the title too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OSError indicates that the issue is running some command on Operating system level.

`Execute sql script` keyword - if it it’s from databaselibrary (your code snippet doesn’t show settings section) takes a name of a file as parameter.

`Replace variables` parameter takes a string and returns a string.

Then you pass a string as a parameter to keyword that takes a filename.  Which leads to a OSError since string is not same as file.

Once you have used the replace variables, you should write that string to a file or check if database library has a keyword to run a script from a string, not from file.